# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Tags: php, mysql

I got a little problem here.
I just exported my EasyPHPV13 databases into EasyPHPV14 on another computer.

When I try to run my php code I get this error :

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
```

The odd thing, it's that on the old computer it works, and on the new computer with EasyPHP V14, with imported databases and localweb data I get the error. I marked the code with /*error for the lines I get error at

My php code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","site_db"); /*error*/

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produse where categorie='1'"); /*error*/

echo "

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th ALIGN=center>Denumire</th>
<th>Specificatii</th>
<th>Pret</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) /*error*/
  {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td ALIGN=center>" . $row['denumire'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td ALIGN=center>" . $row['specificatii'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td ALIGN=center>" . $row['pret'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con); /*error*/
?>
```

Comment: Since I see it's failing right at the connect (based on your error comment), is the credential the same on the new database?   Still root / root?

Comment: Additionally, I noticed you exported your databases...  did you move everything between servers?   As in...  is your web server and DB server on the same box?

Answer (score -2):

Switch around the $con and the query.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Sidenote: I did NOT downvote this. The most likely reason why you got a downvote is because the OP is using `mysqli_*` functions and not `mysql_*` --- Consider deleting your answer to regain your rep points. ;-)